# Unity C# yield return new WaitForSeconds is stopping coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to use a coroutine to make the player wait a little before shooting a new bullet but it never gets past the yield. Here's the code

```
 protected override void Start () {
     base.Start ();
     animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
     score = GameManager.instance.playerScore;
     playerLives = GameManager.instance.playerLife;
 }
 void Update(){
     int horizontal = (int)Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
     AttemptMove (horizontal, 0);
     if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
         if(canShoot){
         Vector3 shootPosition = transform.position + new Vector3 (0, 0.5f, 0);
         Instantiate (bullet, shootPosition, Quaternion.identity);
         StartCoroutine(Shoot());
         }
     }
 }

 IEnumerator Shoot(){
     Debug.Log("Start");
     canShoot=false;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (shootingTimeDelay);
     canShoot=true;
     Debug.Log("End");
 }
```

shootingTimeDelay is set to 1.1f. I am not destroying my gameObject anywhere and it works properly in other scripts in my project.

It never prints End. I don't get what is wrong

Comment: `Time.timeScale` is greater then `0`?

Comment: It's the c# Gods telling you _not_ to use coroutines

Comment: simply use `Invoke()` for timers in Unity

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Thank you so much for the comment man. Over 2 years passed, but you still helped me solve a problem I've been trying to fix for a day now. TY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say don't use a coroutine for something like this.

Trying doing this and see if you get better restults

```
private float time = 0;

public float fireTime = 1.1f;

private void Update()
{
  time += Time.deltaTime;

  if(Input.GetKeyDown("space") && time >= fireTime)
  {
    Vector3 shootPosition = transform.position + new Vector3 (0, 0.5f, 0);
    Instantiate (bullet, shootPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    time = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is much better solution then using coroutines but still we should find the problem in OP code.

Comment: This solution works just perfect. I am waiting before accepting it because I'd like to know the problem in my code

Comment: There has to be an external factor in your code. I made a test out of your coroutine and it worked just fine. I would take a look at script execute order, or any other classes that might even remotely be involved

Comment: What is the value of shootingTimeDelay when you call? Is it public and if so what is the value in Editor?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the bug. I had a method in its superclass that called StopAllCoroutines but for some reason i never tought of it until now. Changed that to StopCoroutine("name of my coroutine") and now it works perfect :)